# How to see new queue MSMQ messages in queue that is bigger than 800-1500 messages?

Tags: c#, msmq

Does the following window:
Computer Management -> Message queueing -> Private queues -> {MyQueue} -> Queue messages
show all the messages from queue or some first 1000 ? And how to see all the messages?

In detail:

I have a private transactional MSMQ queue and it is displyed correctly in Queue messages window until the number of messages in the queue exceedes 800-1500. Then, when new message is added, it does not appear in the {MyQueue} -> Queue messages window, however, in Message Queueing -> Private Queues window I can see that the number of messages has grown in myqueue.

I tried to add a message via code (the behaviour is as described above):

```
    // Create MSMQ message
    var msg = new Message();
    msg.Body = "Hello world";
    msg.Label = "Now you see me";
    msg.UseDeadLetterQueue = true;
    msg.UseJournalQueue = true;
    msg.AcknowledgeType = AcknowledgeTypes.FullReachQueue | AcknowledgeTypes.FullReceive;
    msg.AdministrationQueue = new MessageQueue(@".\private$\audit");

    // Send MSMQ message
    var mq = new MessageQueue(@"FormatName:DIRECT=OS:.\private$\myqueue");
    mq.Send(msg, MessageQueueTransactionType.Single);
```

What is more interesting, I can retrieve the "invisible" message in code:

```
    // Retrieve MSMQ message
    mq.MessageReadPropertyFilter.SetAll();
    var allMessages = mq.GetAllMessages();

    DateTime today = DateTime.Now.Date;
    var messages = allMessages.Where(m => m.ArrivedTime > today).OrderByDescending(m => m.ArrivedTime).ToList();
```

There are no explicit limits on this queue set.

How could I see all the messages in the queue?

a) in Computer Management -> Message queueing -> Private queues -> {MyQueue} -> Queue messages

b) or in some other free tool ?

Answer (score 2):

I think it's a limitation in windows.
However, I can suggest
MSMQ QXplorer

Free and Open source.

http://msmqqxplorer.svn.sourceforge.net/

latest download available at:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/msmqqxplorer/files/latest/download?source=files

Comment: Dzięki. The project's code is terrible but it is a good starting point to enhance this solution.